# Hot Module Replacement always full reload

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

HMR always full reload everytime I change something in index.js. The only clue I got is it has something to do with [`module.hot.accept()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#accept), but I'm new to webpack and reading the very technical docs doesn't help.
**Here is the details:**

- [The warning from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN06A.png)
- [My project's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70qwv.png)
- package.json:

```json
    {
      "name": "webpack-shits",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "dev": "webpack serve",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "webpack": "^5.72.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
      }
    }
```

- webpack.config.js:

```js
    const path = require("path");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    
    module.exports = {
        mode: "development",
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: {
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
            path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
            clean: true,
        },
        devtool: "inline-source-map",
        devServer: {
            static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css/i,
                    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                    type: "asset/resource",
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                title: "Webpack Shits",
                template: path.join(__dirname, "src/template.html"),
                favicon: path.join(__dirname, "src/logo.svg"),
            }),
        ],
    };
```

- index.js:

```js
    import style from "./main.css";
    
    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerText = "Heading";
    document.body.append(h1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the following code:

```js
import "./main.css";

const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
h1.innerText = "Heading1";
document.body.append(h1);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.dispose(() => {
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
  });
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

`module.hot.accept()` will [accept updates for itself.](https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#accept-self)

The HMR logs in browser console:

```bash
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR]  - ./src/index.js
[HMR] App is up to date.
```

Comment: Works like a charm! But does this mean I have to manually write `module.hot.dispose()` and `module.hot.accept()` for every child component (e.g. if I were to use React)?